# Size of a string in bytes (windows)

Tags: perl

I'm attempting to have a progress indicator when processing a large file by counting the [`length`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/length.html) of each string.  Unfortunately, it's counting each line ending `"\r\n"` as a single character, therefore leading to a drift of my running total.

The following script demonstrates:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $file = 'length_vs_size.txt';

open my $fh, '>', $file;

my $length = 0;
while (<DATA>) {
    $length += length;
    print $fh $_;
}
close $fh;

my $size = -s $file;

print "Length = $length\n";
print "Size = $size\n";

__DATA__
11...chars
22...chars
33...chars
44...chars
55...chars
```

Using Strawberry Perl, this outputs:

```
Length = 55
Size = 60
```

As one would expect, when viewing the file in a hex editor, each line ending is actually `"\r\n"`, taking two bytes.  Therefore the total file size is 5 more than the length.

Is there a way to count the length of bytes of a string?

I've played around with the [`bytes`](http://perldoc.perl.org/bytes.html) pragma, and even a little bit of [`unpack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html), but no luck yet.  I'm hoping for a generalized solution other than just adding 1 to my length call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Windows, files have the `:crlf` encoding layer enabled by default. On reading, this transforms `\r\n` to `\n`, and reverses this when writing. This means that scripts which assume Unix line endings won't break quite as often.

If you don't want this behaviour, remove any PerlIO layers by using the `:raw` pseudolayer:

```
binmode STDIN, ':raw'; # for one handle
```

or

```
use open IO => ':raw';  # for all handles
```

(of course, this is a simplification, and the actual behavior of `:raw` is explained in [`PerlIO`](https://metacpan.org/pod/PerlIO))

Comment: ty.  So for my example, I'd need to do `binmode DATA, ':raw';` so that the `\r`'s aren't striped from the data block, and another `binmode $fh, ':raw';` so that extra ones aren't added when outputting to a file.

Comment: Note: `use open IO => ':raw';` does not work for my specific example.  Outputs length=55, size=60.  Might have to do with the DATA handle, but even then I'd expect an output of 55 & 55, instead of the desired 60 & 60.

Comment: Confirmed `use open IO => ':raw';` only effects new calls to `open`, so doesn't effect the `DATA` handle.  It will return 55 & 55 like I thought.  Also, `binmode STDIN;` should be sufficient, since `':raw'` is default.

Comment: @Miller thanks for this additional info – I don't really `use open` myself, so I wasn't sure about it's actual semantics.  We both learned something today :)

Comment: `use open` doesn't work for DATA because DATA is already opened before `use open` is encountered (on account of DATA being the file handle use to read the file to compile it).